# Copying and pasting text from windows to a remote linux file

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

I have an amazon ec2 instance hosting ubuntu 14.04. I need to copy a paste a win 7 textfile on my local machine, into a textfile on ec2. Is there a text editor that would support cutting and pasting available in ubuntu 14.04 or what is the best way to cut and paste info into a linux file . I created the file on amazon using

```
$ vim text1.txt
```

Comment: I usually just use `cat > filename` in putty and then right-click to insert the content from the clipboard... But that's probably not the 'best way' as that is always highly opinion based. For that reason this isn't a very good question for SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cut and paste are an operation on the local operating system so your remote linux box is not going to support it directly.

That said, your terminal emulation will accept a paste operation (usually with `Shift-Insert` on Windows if I recall), so you can just go into insert mode in `vi` and paste - the characters just get inserted as if you had typed them all.

The suggestion to use `cat > filename` also works but I have found that some terminal emulations will hang when pasting large chunks to the command line where stuffing them into `vi` has worked fine.

Comment: I've actually settled on http://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su. This works pretty well.